# Unknown template object error with handlebars 2.0 runtime

Tags: javascript, exception, backbone.js, handlebars.js

[I have published all my code as a runnable that uses express for loading static content](http://runnable.com/VCo0IOUe9gEbVWLQ/express_handlebars_error-for-node-js)

I have precompiled this handlebars template:

```
 <img src="{{coverImage}}"/>
<ul>
    <li>{{title}}</li>
    <li>{{author}}</li>
    <li>{{releaseDate}}</li>
    <li>{{keywords}}</li>
</ul>
```

Delete

I have obtained this function:

```
    (function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['bookTemplate'] = template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = "", stack1, helper, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


  buffer += "<img src=\"";
  if (helper = helpers.coverImage) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.coverImage); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "\"/>\r\n    <ul>\r\n        <li>";
  if (helper = helpers.title) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.title); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</li>\r\n        <li>";
  if (helper = helpers.author) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.author); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</li>\r\n        <li>";
  if (helper = helpers.releaseDate) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.releaseDate); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</li>\r\n        <li>";
  if (helper = helpers.keywords) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
  else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.keywords); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; }
  buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
    + "</li>\r\n    </ul>\r\n<button class=\"delete\">Delete</button>";
  return buffer;
  });
})();
```

I have added the scripts like this:

```
 <script src="js/lib/handlebars.runtime-v2.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/templates.js"></script>
```

I see in `Chrome Dev Tools` that both scripts load.

However when I use it like this:

```
 //inside a Backbone view
 template:Handlebars.templates.bookTemplate
```

I get this error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Unknown template object: function handlebars.runtime-v2.0.0.js:455template handlebars.runtime-v2.0.0.js:455hb.template handlebars.runtime-v2.0.0.js:644(anonymous function) templates.js:3(anonymous function)
```

I get this error at line 455 in `handlebars runtime @2.0.0` in the function `template`,upon doing a little debugging I find that `templateSpec` is a function,but `templateSpec.main` is `undefined`:

```
  //this function makes a call to templates['bookTemplate'] = template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {...} in the `bookTemplate.js`
  function template(templateSpec, env) {
/* istanbul ignore next */
if (!env) {
  throw new Exception("No environment passed to template");
}
//error occurs here: 
if (!templateSpec || !templateSpec.main) {
  throw new Exception('Unkn own template object: ' + typeof templateSpec);
}
...
```

Additionally I find that Handlebars.templates is an empty object.

What is going on here?

Comment: Anything in [here](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets/issues/110) sound familiar? How about any of the other [Google hits](https://www.google.ca/#q=handlebars+Uncaught+Error%3A+Unknown+template+object).

Comment: @muistooshort I disable the browser cache in Chrome,the google hits are too complex,what Im doing is simple,Im precompiling a handlebars template and using it with the runtime library,no server yet,using `file://`,updated the post to show location of error

Comment: @muistooshort the `templateSpec.main` is `undefined`

Comment: Can you try it through a web server? `file://` is just trouble. Can you replicate the problem at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @muistooshort tried it using the `http-server` node module,still getting the same error.I have published it as a [runnable with express](http://runnable.com/VCo0IOUe9gEbVWLQ/express_handlebars_error-for-node-js)

Comment: Try with the gool old way: compile your template with a simple '<div>hello</div>' and add items till you get the error.

Comment: Perhaps the templates were not compiled with version 2.0.0. To update the globally installed handlebars: `npm update -g handlebars`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you precompiled that template with handlebars 1.3.x, you are running into a breaking change with 2.0. Make sure the server/build tools is running the 2.0 handlebars compiler.

Comment: could you also add that `handlebars` npm module has to be installed globally

Comment: Generally speaking, that's not a hard and fast requirement. If using a js build system, it generally just has it as a requirement somewhere in its hiearchy. Even if you're using a Makefile in your project, you can just reference `node_modules/.bin/handlebars` instead of relying on a global installation. If using an npm script its even easier as you can reference depenency executables from the _package.json` `scripts` section without specifying the path into node_modules.

Comment: @vamsiampolu The `handlebars` npm module does not need to be installed at all. You don't even need to explicitly install the handlebars bower component.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you compiled the template with the same Handlebars version as the runtime?

I'm just trying Handlebars 2.0 , and my compiled templates have `[6,'>= 2.0.0']` in the compiler field. Your compiled template suggests it was compiled with Handlebars 1.x.

Comment: I don't see why you deleted my answer, as:
1/ It was correct (see the accepted answer)
2/ I can't comment on posts that aren't mine anyway.